# NLP - information extraction in Python (spaCy)

Tags: python, nlp, information-extraction, spacy

I am attempting to extract this type of information from the following paragraph structure:

```
 women_ran men_ran kids_ran walked
         1       2        1      3
         2       4        3      1
         3       6        5      2

text = ["On Tuesday, one women ran on the street while 2 men ran and 1 child ran on the sidewalk. Also, there were 3 people walking.", "One person was walking yesterday, but there were 2 women running as well as 4 men and 3 kids running.", "The other day, there were three women running and also 6 men and 5 kids running on the sidewalk. Also, there were 2 people walking in the park."]
```

I am using Python's `spaCy` as my NLP library. I am newer to NLP work and am hoping for some guidance as to what would be the best way to extract this tabular information from such sentences.

If it was simply a matter of identifying whether there were individuals running or walking, I would just use `sklearn` to fit a classification model, but the information that I need to extract is obviously more granular than that (I am trying to retrieve subcategories and values for each). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to use the dependency parse for this. You can see a visualisation of your example sentence using [the displaCy visualiser](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=On%20Tuesday%2C%20one%20women%20ran%20on%20the%20street%20while%202%20men%20ran%20and%201%20child%20ran%20on%20the%20sidewalk.%20Also%2C%20there%20were%203%20people%20walking.&model=en&cpu=1&cph=0).

You could implement the rules you need a few different ways — much like how there are always multiple ways to write an XPath query, DOM selector, etc.

Something like this should work:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
docs = [nlp(t) for t in text]
for i, doc in enumerate(docs):
    for j, sent in enumerate(doc.sents):
        subjects = [w for w in sent if w.dep_ == 'nsubj']
        for subject in subjects:
            numbers = [w for w in subject.lefts if w.dep_ == 'nummod']
            if len(numbers) == 1:
                print('document.sentence: {}.{}, subject: {}, action: {}, numbers: {}'.format(i, j, subject.text, subject.head.text, numbers[0].text))
```

For your examples in `text` you should get:

```
document.sentence: 0.0, subject: men, action: ran, numbers: 2
document.sentence: 0.0, subject: child, action: ran, numbers: 1
document.sentence: 0.1, subject: people, action: walking, numbers: 3
document.sentence: 1.0, subject: person, action: walking, numbers: One
```

Comment: I've never written an XPath query or a DOM selector. Could you explain please?

Comment: @kathystehl XPath specifies a location in an XML (HTML) document. So an XPath query is a way to find a particular element in XML or HTML. See [wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). A DOM selector is any CSS element `id` or `class` in an HTML document (the DOM is the data structure for an HTML/XML document/tree that you work with in javascript, etc). So you can filter by id and class to find elements. In NLP, a dependency parser turns unstructured text into a tree data structure similar to HTML with tags that can be queried like this with DOM selector filters and XPath queries.